# Discord API for Search, Channels, and Messages

Tags: discord

I'm new to Discord and would like to know whether Discord provides APIs for the following purposes:

1. I would like to send a search keyword in the request and would like to receive in response all public servers / channels that are a match. (This is similar to the 'Explore Public Server' functionality available in the Discord web and desktop front-ends (but not on mobile devices)
2. The user goes through the search results and select one of the results. Now, I would like to send this server (server name or server Id) in the request and expect to get the list of public channels on this server.
3. The user then selects one of the public channels. Now I send the channel id in the request and expect to receive the messages along with their corresponding usernames and datetime they were posted in the channel.

I tried to refer to the API documentation but was unable to figure out. I plan to use Java API (JAX-RS) with Jersey.

Thanks,
Dicky